# jQuery change event not firing for input field

Tags: jquery, events

I'm trying to remove an alert on a form when a user fixes an empty field.
My generalized code works for all input elements where the user has to type in the field, but my input that has a popup calendar does not fire the "change" event if the date is placed in the field by the system.  I thought the change event fired when the field lost its focus?

```
        $("#my_input").change(function() {
            $(".StatusBox").html("");
            $(this).unbind("change");
        });
```

I have another piece of code that runs after this and changes the input field(user clicking on a calendar date and therefore updating the input). Shouldn't that fire the change event?

Comment: The code the runs subsequently cannot fire the change event because this routine `unbind`s the change event. Am I misunderstanding, or is there need for clarification in the question?

Comment: The change event is triggered when something has changed, like the user has typed a character. The blur event happens on loss of focus. How do you know your change event isn't triggered? Did you put a console.log inside?

Comment: The unbind only happens after the change fires which would also empty my statusbox of the error message.  I know both aren't happening because my error message is still showing.

Comment: @JayMcVety You may want a console.log or alert in there just to make sure.  If this selector $(".StatusBox").html(""); is bad, it would not clear it out, and it may just be a assumption that it is not firing.

Comment: Yeah I removed the console.log statement to make it shorter for this post.  I decided to just trigger the "change" event manually after the user clicks a date in the calendar.  Simpler.  And the statusbox clears for every other input field, just not one where the system updates the input without user keying in data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can programmatically force a change event via the `trigger('change')` method:

```
$('#elementID').trigger('change');
```

This assumes, of course, that `$('#elementID')` is <sub>(still)</sub> bound to a change event...

Comment: This works.  I'll just trigger change manually when the user clicks a date.  Thanks!

Comment: @JayMcVety I totally skipped over the fact in your initial post that it was JavaScript that was populating the field.  This is what you would always have to do when JavaScript is changing a field.  The browser will not fire the change event unless it is being changed by the user.

Answer (score 9):

Use something like this, it always works.

```
$(function() {
    $("#my_input").on("change paste keyup", function() {
       alert($(this).val()); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried use **$("#my_input").on('change', function** ... ?

It works slightly different than *bind*, and you can put it in a function to be re-run for new objects created on demand (so, it don't need necessarily to be inside the "ready" statement).

Comment: Julio is right, this could work as well, except that the example would not pickup the input if it is coming in after the page is loaded. The selector has to be on something static that exists.  Doing something like $(document).on('change', '#my_input', function() { }); would get it done.

Comment: Thanks to complement the answer Paul. In fact it crossed my mind the 'event' -> 'selector' procedure, but for some distraction of mine I failed point to this idea too. Great catch! ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you are attaching the event before the element is loaded on the page.  Maybe try doing this to let the page finish loading before attaching the event

```
$(function() {

    $("#my_input").change(function() {
             $(".StatusBox").html("");
             $(this).unbind("change");
     });
});
```

Comment: I'm only binding the change event after the form is submitted by the user and checked for empty fields.  It's definitely after the page has loaded and the error stating my field is empty shows up.

Comment: I was binding my file input field on page load and this suggestion solved my problem. Thanks